# Erlang - где и кем используется ?

Tags: erlang

Где ниша этого языка ? В чём его преимущество кто знает ? Говорят он нужен для телекоммуникационных проектов, но это как, драйвера писать для сетевой карточки на этом языке ? Кто его использует, отзовитесь, расскажите !

Comment: Ну уж точно не драйвера. Наверно имеются ввиду системы управления телекомуникациями.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Где ниша этого языка

Высоконагруженные и отказоустойчивые сетевые сервисы.

> В чём его преимущество кто знает ?

1. Очень лёгкие (green threads) потоки.
2. Изоляция процессов и их состояний — нет разделяемых данных.
3. Общение между процессами посредством посылки immutable сообщений.
4. Мощная и гибкая кластеризация из коробки.
5. Возможность hot-update — обновления работающего в production кода без отключения пользователей, в том числе, и с миграцией структур данных на новую версию.
6. Удобная концепция обработки ошибок.
7. Удобнейшая работа с отдельными битами — неоценимое подспорье при реализации коммуникационных протоколов.
8. Концепция гипервизоров.
9. Удобнейший, встроенный в язык, механизм удалённого вызова.
10. Отсутствие присваиваний в их традиционном понимании — отсутствие проблем с синхронизацией.
11. Быстрое и приятное вхождение в ЯП — через неделю уже можно клепать вполне годный production-ready код.
12. Стабильная и быстрая VM.
13. *[субъективизм]* Функциональный ЯП (pattern matching, хорошо оптимизированные хвостовые рекурсии и т.д.). *[/субъективизм]*

Comment: @falstaf, а как относиться к [вот этому](http://lurkmore.to/Erlang)?

Comment: @avp, с юмором, как же иначе.

Comment: @falstaf лучше вашего ответа просто не существует !

Comment: А если честно, кто-нибудь сам написал хоть один "продакшн", ну, или использует программы, написанные на Erlang?

Comment: Писал и пишу иногда, если задача соответствующая. А из известного ПО, написанного на сабже — ejabberd и wings3d.